# Enable Submit Comment Without Page Reload (Using Ajax)?

Tags: comments, jquery, javascript, ajax

When user writes a comment and hits the submit button, WordPress reloads the page, before the comment is shown to the user.

Is there an Ajax-based solution that allows users to submit questions dynamically, without refreshing the whole page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the following javascrip file `wpse54189-ajax-comments.js` inside your plug-in folder - say `plugins/plug-in-name/js` (or if this must go your theme, in your theme folder).

```
/*
 * jQuery autoResize (textarea auto-resizer)
 * @copyright James Padolsey http://james.padolsey.com
 * @version 1.04
 */

(function(a){a.fn.autoResize=function(j){var b=a.extend({onResize:function(){},animate:true,animateDuration:150,animateCallback:function(){},extraSpace:20,limit:1000},j);this.filter('textarea').each(function(){var c=a(this).css({resize:'none','overflow-y':'hidden'}),k=c.height(),f=(function(){var l=['height','width','lineHeight','textDecoration','letterSpacing'],h={};a.each(l,function(d,e){h[e]=c.css(e)});return c.clone().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name').css({position:'absolute',top:0,left:-9999}).css(h).attr('tabIndex','-1').insertBefore(c)})(),i=null,g=function(){f.height(0).val(a(this).val()).scrollTop(10000);var d=Math.max(f.scrollTop(),k)+b.extraSpace,e=a(this).add(f);if(i===d){return}i=d;if(d>=b.limit){a(this).css('overflow-y','');return}b.onResize.call(this);b.animate&&c.css('display')==='block'?e.stop().animate({height:d},b.animateDuration,b.animateCallback):e.height(d)};c.unbind('.dynSiz').bind('keyup.dynSiz',g).bind('keydown.dynSiz',g).bind('change.dynSiz',g)});return this}})(jQuery);


/*
 * Source: wp-comment-master WordPress Plugin
 * URL: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-comment-master/
 * Author URI: http://yjlblog.com
 * Version: 1.7
 * Last Updated: 2011-6-6
 */

   var $commentlist=jQuery('.commentlist');
   var $respond=jQuery('#respond');
   var $message=jQuery('<span class="yjl-mes"></span>').appendTo("#commentform");;
   var $list=$commentlist.children();
   var totalCom=$list.length;
   var $textarea=$respond.find('#comment').attr('rows','8');

   var currentPage=0,$number,numPerPage,totalPage,$reply;

   //track a reply comment
   jQuery('.comment-reply-link').live('click',function(){
       $reply=true;
   });
   var $cancel=jQuery('#cancel-comment-reply-link').click(function(){
       $reply=false;
   });

   /*
    *if Ajax comment posting is enabled
    */
   jQuery('#commentform').submit(function(){
       jQuery.ajax({
         beforeSend:function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since","0");
            $message.empty().append('<img src="'+yjlSettings.gifUrl+'" alt="processing...">');
         },
         type:'post',
         url:jQuery(this).attr('action'),
         data:jQuery(this).serialize(),
         dataType:'html',
         error:function(xhr){
             if(xhr.status==500){
               $message.empty().append(xhr.responseText.split('<p>')[1].split('</p>')[0]);
             }
             else if(xhr.status=='timeout'){
               $message.empty().append((yjlSettings.timeOut!=''?yjlSettings.timeOut:'Error:Server time out,try again!'));
             }
             else{
               $message.empty().append((yjlSettings.fast!=''?yjlSettings.fast:'Please slow down,you are posting to fast!'));
             }
         },
         success:function(data){
            $message.empty().append((yjlSettings.thank!=''?yjlSettings.thank:'Thank you for your comment!'));
            $newComList=jQuery(data).find('.commentlist');
            if(totalCom>0){
               if($reply)$cancel.trigger('click');
               else {
                   if(yjlSettings.order=='desc')currentPage=0;
                   else { getTotal($newComList);currentPage=totalPage-1;}
               }
               if(yjlSettings.pagination=='disable' || yjlSettings.pagerPos=='after')
                        $commentlist.prev().replaceWith($newComList.prev());
               else $commentlist.prev().prev().replaceWith($newComList.prev());                     
               $commentlist.replaceWith($newComList);                            
            }else{
               if(yjlSettings.repForm=='disable')$newComList.prev().andSelf().insertBefore($respond);
               else $newComList.prev().andSelf().insertAfter($respond);
            }
            $commentlist=$newComList;
            if(yjlSettings.pagination!='disable')pagination();
            $textarea.val(''); 
         }
       });//end of ajax
      return false;
   });//end of submit function

   if(yjlSettings.autoGrow!='disable'){
      $textarea.autoResize({
       // On resize:
       onResize : function() {
        jQuery(this).css({opacity:0.8});
      },
      // After resize:
      animateCallback : function() {
        jQuery(this).css({opacity:1});
      },
      // Quite slow animation:
      animateDuration : 300,
      // More extra space:
      extraSpace : 20
      });
   }
```

The above code uses a variable which stores the location of an 'ajax' loading image (see below). We need to give this variable the location of the image, which should be your plug-in folder, say `plugins/plug-in-name/img`, (or, again, if you must, your theme's folder). We will use use `wp_localise_script`.

First though, we need register this script with WordPress, listing jquery as a dependency:

```
add_action('init','wpse54189_register_script');
function wpse54189_register_script(){
    //Register script
    wp_register_script( 'wpse54189_ajax_comment', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__ ).'js/wpse54189-ajax-comments.js',array('jquery'));

    //Add global variable storing ajax image
    wp_localize_script( 'wpse54189_ajax_comment', 'yjlSettings', array(
         'gifUrl'=> plugin_dir_path(__FILE__ ).'img/ajax-loader.gif',

         /* remove this line if you don't want the comment textbox's height
         to increase with the size of comment. */
         'autoGrow'=> 'enable'
    ));

}
```

Then when you wish to enqueue the file: `wp_enqueue_script('wpse54189_ajax_comment')` - this will automatically print the variables and ensure jquery is loaded before hand.

This can be placed inside template files, or for plug-ins, you can enqueue the script on a hook (for instance the `comment_form_before` hook):

```
add_action('comment_form_before','wpse54189_register_script'){
     wp_enqueue_script('wpse54189_ajax_comment')
}
```

You can get a nice Ajax loading gif from [here](http://ajaxload.info/). Or simply use this:

[image: Loading gif]

All the JavaScript code was grabbed from [wp-comment-master](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-comment-master/) plugin (of course, I removed the unnecessary snippets — just kept what's needed).

Comment: You really should enqueue scripts. Also, use wp_localize_script to add javascript global variables to a page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a lot of solutions, check it here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=ajax+comments

Comment: **(1)** I did not want to use a plugin. **(2)** I just wanted one feature — the page shouldn't reload when user submits a comment. **(3)** I had the solution which I wanted to share. Hence the question :)

Comment: @AahanKrish download a plugin and take a look how it is implemented there ;)

Comment: Exactly. That's what I did!

Comment: @AahanKrish then my answer is correct :D